# How to search for pictures of two people in iPhoto?

Tags: photos.app, search

iPhoto has the ability to recognize faces. You can tag them with names, which I have done for my relatives. Now I want two find all pictures in which two specific people are. Just typing "A and B" in the search bar of iPhoto does not work. Is there any way for such a query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a smart album using the "Person includes [name]" multiple times with the "Match [all] of the following conditions" option selected.

[image: Smart Album Options]