# How to find Couples only photos in Apple Photos

Tags: macos, photos, photos.app, search, album

How do I search couples photos? I want to find photos that contains exactly the two people, and no one else.

When we do the following, it provides photos that has both the people, and other folks as well.

[image: Search People]

[Image above is referenced from the answer here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/294453/how-to-search-for-pictures-of-two-people-in-iphoto)

Comment: In Photos you can only do it by adding rules "Person does not include xxx" for all the other people who might be in the same photo as Teddy and Foster.

Comment: Thank you @Gilby. That is nuts. Hopefully Apple will add this feature.